# How can we Sort a dictionary<List<int>, List<int>> on the basis of two fields from value

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary, max, min

As a part of key I am storing a List and in Value I want to store max and min values of that list. Later there will be many lists like that. I need to sort for the dictionary having minimum possible maximum element value and minimum possible minimum element value

Something like

```
var map= Dictionary<List<int>, List<int>>()
```

Consider few list like

```
List1=[21,65,98,9,2] List2=[3,46,78,09,17] List3=[3,6,0,98]
```

respective min and max for list1, list2 and list3 are [2,98], [3,78] and [0,98]. These values will be stored in the dictionary value(with associated list as key).

I want to sort in the dictionary, keeping a track of both min and max value.
Something like:

```
map= {[3,6,0,98] ,[0,98]} , {[21,65,98,9,2],[2,98]}, {[3,46,78,09,17], [3,78]}
```

Comment: There is a datatype called SortedDictionary in c#. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=net-5.0. It might help.

Comment: If there are two items, one with value `[1,5]` and one with value `[2,6]`, which should come first when sorted?

Comment: You cannot have a collection as a key. Also, keys must be unique. You could use a ValueTuple to store minimum and maximum values as key, but only if this pair of values is unique.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Sure you can, the value is just the reference to the object.. not a practical key for most situations but you still can.. references to objects are also very unique.

Comment: Some code might help: we can't see the context of how you want to do this

Comment: @ZachHutchins, The key in my suggestion would be a ValueTuple of  `(int, int)`, which is not a reference.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I understand, But you said you cannot have a collection as a key and you can

Comment: @ZachHutchins, Value tuples are a feature available in C# 7.0 and later. They are not a collection. See: [Tuple types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) and on [TutorialsTeacher: C# - ValueTuple](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/valuetuple).

Comment: @devNull first we should et [1,5] then [2,6]

Comment: @AabhasJain I now realize that example didn't actually illustrate the problem. So what about between `[1,6]` and `[2,5]`? i.e. should the minimum minimum value take precedence over the minimum maximum value? Or vice versa?

Comment: @devNull minimum maximum value should be taking the precedence, if they are equal in that case pick the minimum minimum

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you really just need to order the dictionary by the Value, which is really just the Min and Max elements from the Key. And the order should go by the Max elements and then by the Min elements if the Max elements are equal. So, given this data:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<List<int>, List<int>>
{
    { new List<int> {3,6,0,98 }, new List<int> {0,98 } },
    { new List<int> {21,65,98,9,2 },new List<int> {2,98 } },
    { new List<int> {3,46,78,09,17 }, new List<int> {3,78 } }
};
```

You can sort the dictionary using the [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Collections_Generic_IComparer___1__) method, passing in a custom [`IComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=net-5.0):

```
var sorted = dictionary.OrderBy(x => x.Value, new MinMaxCompararer());
```

`MinMaxComparer` here looks like:

```
class MinMaxCompararer : IComparer<List<int>>
{
    public int Compare([AllowNull] List<int> x, [AllowNull] List<int> y)
    {
        int maxCompare = x[1].CompareTo(y[1]);
        return maxCompare == 0
            ? x[0].CompareTo(y[0])
            : maxCompare;
    }
}
```

With this, iterating over the elements shows them sorted as you'd expect:

```cs
foreach (KeyValuePair<List<int>, List<int>> item in sorted)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: [{string.Join(",", item.Key)}]; Value: [{string.Join(",", item.Value)}]");
}
```

```
Key: [3,46,78,9,17]; Value: [3,78]
Key: [3,6,0,98]; Value: [0,98]
Key: [21,65,98,9,2]; Value: [2,98]
```